# Contar valores com dados especificos no MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, query

Tenho uma lista imensa de valores que preciso fazer contagem, o exemplo é, tenho 4000 códigos de barras e nesses 4000, 2000 estão marcados na coluna *sem estoque* com um *sim*.

**Melhores explicações**

Na contagem de total de código de barras eu uso esse código

```html
<?php
$result=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from n_emails");
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "Total de emails ativos: ";
echo $data['total'];
echo "Total de emails inativos: ";
echo $data['total'];
?>
```

Teria como eu especificar nesse código a contagem da tabela apenas para quem está marcado como *sim* na coluna *sem estoque*?

Para ajudar ainda mais, a estrutura da `table` está assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O estou tentando** é modificar a query que está no `php` para que conte apenas *emails* que estejam com um *s* na coluna *ativo*.

Alguma luz de como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, basicamente o que você precisa utilizar é um where na sua consulta, tenta o seguinte código:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from n_emails WHERE ativo='s'");
```

Se você utilizar com group by também pode funcionar, veja:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT ativo, count(*) as total from n_emails GROUP BY ativo");
```

Este código irá retornar duas linhas, uma com a quantidade de ativos e outra com a quantidade de inativos, ai basta você desenvolver a lógica para a exibição.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 3):

Segue uma *query* que conta os ativos, os não ativos e o total numa consulta só, retornando tudo na mesma linha, para simplificar o uso no PHP:

<sub>(quebras de linha para facilitar a leitura)</sub>

```
SELECT
   SUM( IF( `ativo`='s', 1, 0 ) ) AS ativos,
   SUM( IF( `ativo`='s', 0, 1 ) ) AS inativos,
   COUNT(*)                       AS total
FROM
   tabela
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/171dd4/1)**.

As colunas serão retornadas em `ativos`, `inativos` e `total`, simplificando a obtenção dos dados já com os nomes corretos.

Obviamente que não há necessidade de retornar as três colunas, duas bastariam para se obter todos os dados, mas deixei completa a *query* para ilustrar.